# Neo4j: retrieve all non-referenced nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple data model with source-[:link]->target. I'd like to find out all the nodes, which have no incoming links e.g. the "roots" of my data model. How do I do that in Cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter on *null* values

```
START target=node(*)
MATCH target<-[r?:link]-source
WHERE r is null
RETURN target
```

For details, refer [Cypher *where* clause documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-where.html#where-filter-on-null-values)

Alternatively, you can also do

```
START target=node(*)
WHERE not(target<-[:link]-source)
RETURN target
```

*Note: not tested

Comment: I was looking for something like this. This is essentially what he will have to do is a whole graph scan, unless he is indexing those root nodes.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. It also works fine for this one: START target=node(*)
MATCH target<-[?]-source
WHERE source is null
RETURN target

Answer (score 2):

```
start n=node(*) 
match n<-[?]-m 
with n, count(m) as c 
where c=0 
return n
```